# apache ssl (443) node.js ssl (8081). Client can't find socket.io.js

Tags: apache, node.js, ssl, amazon-web-services, socket.io

I have spent two days on this.  Hoping someone has the answer.

I have an apache server running SSL on port 443.
I have a node.js server running SSL on port 8081.

In the client, I am trying to include the socket.io/socket.io.js file as follows:

```
<script src="https://my_url.com:8081/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

I don't get a 404 (not found).  In the Chrome javascript console, I get Status = (failed) and Type = undefined.  I have tried suggestions I've found (using src="localhost.." etc, but they don't work either).

It works for my http version.  I include the file like this:

```
<script src="http://my_url.com:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Not sure why the SSL version is not working.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!!

Comment: can you explain in more detail the architecture of the system, i dont understand why you do have two servers running ssl and who delivers the script

Comment: I am using apache to serve my php pages for login etc.  Then the app page includes all of the script files etc.  That is where I am calling the socket.io.js.  If I don't make the node.js ssl, then I get the warning "...served insecure content from http://my_url.com:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js".

Comment: I couldn't get the node https server to work. But found another solution.  I am using Amazon Load Balancer to terminate the SSL and send http to the Node server.  It is working great.  I do the same for my SSL Apache traffic.  FYI - if you go this route, you need to use the TCP (SSL) and TCP options in the load balancer for the Node traffic.

Answer (score 1):

**DO NOT SET THE ProxyPass to Localhost! That's not working!**

Do this in your Apache configuraton:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName domain.com
    SSLProxyEngine On
    RequestHeader set Front-End-Https "On"
    ProxyPass / https://domain.com:3000/ retry=1 acquire=3000 timeout=600 Keepalive=On
    ProxyPassReverse / https://domain.com:3000/

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateKeyFile    /etc/ssl/private/domain.com.key
    SSLCertificateFile       /etc/ssl/certs/domain.com.crt
    SSLCertificateChainFile  /etc/ssl/certs/chaincert.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, Nodejs can also have SSL:

```
var express = require('express');
var connect = require('connect');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');

var ssl_options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/private/domain.com.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/certs/domain.com.crt'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/certs/domain.com.ca')
};

var server = require('https').createServer(ssl_options, app);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(port, function(err) {
    console.log(colors.green('https server running on port ' + port));
});
```

And in your client do this:

```
var socket = io.connect('https://domain.com:3000', { path: '/socket.io', 'flash policy port': 3000 });
```

for me, this is working fine!

Answer (score 0):

from your comment i guess you have a CORS problem:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

If you change protocoll the origin is not the same following the same origin policy. You have to include a header for this.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

The warning about insecure content is a hint what caused the problem: You are trying to access an origin via script which is not the origin of the script. This is a security issue as it may provide a leak allowing harmful scripts to be injected into the page

Comment: browsers handle this very differently. Some load the scripts but do not execute them some send an OPTIONS Request to the site and refuse to load the script

Comment: I looked into this.  But I couldn't understand why my http version works:  <script src="http://my_url.com:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>.  When I use this (when my apache is running on port 80 and node.js on port 8080), it works.  Are there different origin policy rules for https?

Comment: Looks like I might have a problem with my node.js ssl setup.  I just tried going to the links directly in the browser and get an SSL error for the secure one, but the socket.io.js file is displayed for the insecure.

Comment: in this case you should post your node.js code in here (just edit your first post), otherwise i cant track down the problem. A good method is using developer tools in the browser and inspect the network tab. E.g. in Chrome F12 and then the network tab

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I think the problem is that I was using a self signed certificate on the node side, rather than the CA one I purchased and have installed on my apache server.  I'm going to fix that, and see if the problem persists.